# Neo4j cypher query to combine results

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using the [Neo4j's console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=pretty_graph), I have the following graph

[image]

I'm trying to query the graph to get 2 rows, 1 for each player, but this is what I have

[image]

How to combine the rows such that for `Player 36`, I only get 1, with a collection of `Season` and each `Season` has a collection of `Month`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that I think satisfies your requirement.  This just takes your query and adds an interim step of aggregating the season and the months together in a map as a season.  Then it collects the new compound season into seasons per player.

```
match (p:Player)-->(s:Season)-->(m:Month)
with p, {season: s, months: collect(m)} as season
return p, collect(season) as seasons
```

**edit:** applied cybersam's sage advice

Comment: It is best for collections to contain homogenous elements. I would replace `[s, collect(m)]` with `{season: s, months: collect(m)}`.